# How to import third party react library in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I want to use [react-infinite-scroller](https://github.com/CassetteRocks/react-infinite-scroller) in a rails project. And I followed these two links https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails/issues/510#issuecomment-207790440

http://rmosolgo.github.io/blog/2016/05/19/how-i-use-sprockets/

Here is what I did:
[image]

I imported it using `//= require ./vendor/InfiniteScroll-v1.0.0`
in application.js and I used it like this:

```
 <InfiniteScroll pageStart={0}>
      <ContentTable
        data={this.state.tableData}
        filterText={this.state.filterText}
        onUserClick={this.handleUserClick}
        dataType={this.props.dataType}
        showPublic={this.state.publicCheckbox}
      />
 </InfiniteScroll>
```

But there is still an error "`ReferenceError: InfiniteScroll is not defined`". What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

There is code missing here. How did you reference it? I can't see how you referenced it, so I will take an educated guess.

The error is saying you did not reference it correctly.

This link should serve as a clue:

https://github.com/seatgeek/react-infinite

and this one:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError